# Javascript - How do I send my variable to my frontend from the promise I use to query the database?

Tags: javascript, sql-server, promise

This is the promise that I use. Im also using the node-mssql package.

```
const loadpictures = () => {
    sql.connect(config).then(pool => {
    return pool.request()
    .query('SELECT Top 20 PhotoURL As src, PostURL As link from Valley_Photos FOR JSON PATH')

    }).then((result) => {
            //console.dir(result);
            sql.close();
            return result['result'].typeOf();

        }).catch(err => {
           console.log(err)
           sql.close();

        })
}

loadpictures()
.then(result => console.log(results))
.catch( err => ErrorHandler(err) );
```

The error I get is:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
```

The console.dir outputs the desired json object.  I just dont know how to pull it out. 
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not returning any promise from `loadpictures` function, therefore, you cannot use `then` statement in your main.

It's pretty easy to return the second promise that you are using with `async/await` :

```
const loadpictures = async () => {
    let pool = await sql.connect(config);
    let req = pool
      .request()
      .query('SELECT Top 20 PhotoURL As src, PostURL As link from Valley_Photos FOR JSON PATH')

     req.then((result) => {
            //console.dir(result);
            sql.close();
            return result['result'].typeOf();

        }).catch(err => {
           console.log(err)
           sql.close();

        })

     return req;
}

loadpictures()
.then(result => console.log(results))
.catch( err => ErrorHandler(err) );
```

On the other side, using only promises is a bit more verbose because you have to return a new promise that resolves with result and rejects with err :

```
const loadpictures = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        sql.connect(config).then(pool => {
            return pool.request()
              .query('SELECT Top 20 PhotoURL As src, PostURL As link from Valley_Photos FOR JSON PATH')

        }).then((result) => {
           //console.dir(result);
           sql.close();
           resolve(result)
        }).catch(err => {
           console.log(err)
           sql.close();
           reject(err);
        })
    }
}

loadpictures()
.then(result => console.log(results))
.catch( err => ErrorHandler(err) );
```

Comment: Second question what is the best method to send "results" to my frontend? Its just a plain html file with some jquery.

Comment: You can simply pass the result to your script as a variable

Answer (score 0):

`then` is undefined because you're not returning a promise from the function. If you didn't need to use `sql.close()` you could simply return `sql` from the function because its a function that returns a promise, but since you do, wrap the `sql` call in a promise and resolve/reject the results/errors.

```
function loadpictures() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    sql
      .connect(config)
      .then(pool => {
        return pool.request().query(query)
      })
      .then(result => {
        sql.close();
        resolve(result['result'].typeOf());
      })
      .catch(err => {
        sql.close();
        reject(err);
      });
  });
}

loadpictures()
  .then(result => console.log(result))
  .catch(err => ErrorHandler(err));
```